# Creating Permutations from DataFrame without Repetition

Tags: python, pandas, permutation

I've searched for a solution to this problem but haven't found anything specific to this problem.
My dataframe is structured like this:

```
   column_1    column_2     column_3
a     2           3            7
b     9           4            3
c     1           5            2
```

I want to find all permutations of the above dataframe without repeating rows or columns in each individual permutation.

The preceding isn't super clear, so here is the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
Out: [(2,4,2),(2,5,3),(9,3,2),(9,5,7),(1,3,3),(1,4,7)]
```

In other words, I expected n! results

The solution I tried was:

```
permutations = list(product(df['column_1'], df['column_2'], df['column_3']))
print(permutations)
```

This returns n^n combinations.

Any help is appreciated! THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) on the row indices and numpy indexing:

```
from itertools import permutations

idx = list(permutations(range(len(df))))

df.to_numpy()[idx, np.arange(df.shape[1])].tolist()
```

output:

```
[[2, 4, 2], [2, 5, 3], [9, 3, 2], [9, 5, 7], [1, 3, 3], [1, 4, 7]]
```

Comment: This is the question I have been meaning to ask the other day. I would like to know in this case why you chose `to_numpy` method. Is it for the ease of slicing? everything is clear I just would like to understand the reason behind this. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `permutations` method of the `itertools` package. This gives you the indices you need for each column.

```
from itertools import permutations
indices = list(permutations('abc', 3))
print(indices)
```